# How to connect simultaneously to two internet sources of Wifi and Mobile?

Tags: debian, wifi, internet

There is the application [Speedify](http://speedify.com/) which tries to do that, but there is no Linux application at the moment so I started to think if it can be done yourself. I have NordVPN account. 
The service connects to its VPN server. 
I think it creates this way a second interface or something to enable the simultaneous access in two sources for internet. 
Technical support answer to my question about the application VPN connection and its release in Linux

> We use a VPN setup to make channel bonding possible. Without a server
>   component, you can only load balance between multiple Internet
>   connections, which means you can assign sockets to different Internet
>   connections. Speedify does channel bonding, which allows you to split
>   even single socket transfers, like video streaming, across multiple
>   Internet connections.
>
> We currently do not have a Linux client available, but we might
>   consider offering on in the future.
>
> Speedify is its own VPN service and is not compatible with other VPN
>   clients or accounts. You cannot use NordVPN to connect to Speedify.

NordVPN answer because I would like to use my own VPN to with/without Speedify for the feature

> Unfortunately we are not aware if it will be working, since if Speedify is only pinging/sending packets to other Wi-fi/mobile data servers then it will work. However if it is providing some kind of encryption, then it might cause issues if it is used with our app.
>
> Also, this app might be switching between networks from time to time. This will require you to reconnect to a VPN server every time you switch a network.

Situation: if you use Speedify, you cannot use NordVPN. This is a big limitation so I want to know what it requires to have a simultaneous connection to two internet sources.

### Proposal from NordVPN

> It would not be possible as from the answer provided by Speedify it looks like in order to use both Wi-Fi and LTE connection you would require to set up a VPN-like service and thus you would no longer be able to connect to actual VPN.

So I think the interface of VPN must be changed to support both connections. 
I think this is what Speedify has done.

OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 1):

Our prayers have been answered and we didn't even know it. [vtrunkd](https://github.com/VrayoSystems/vtrunkd) is an open source SD WAN daemon for linux (network link bonding/trunking/aggregation and multichannel VPN daemon).

This would be like using Speedify but you would be running the bonding VPN server. I haven't tried it yet but it's been around for 3 years now. I'd imagine that with some determination, one could get it to work.

Comment: Where is the documentation?

Comment: The "Support" link is dead and the last commit is 3 years old, so I'll pass.